# Integral with respect to the sum of two complex measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Does the integral value w.r.t. the sum of two complex measures coincide with the sum of the integral values w.r.t. each of the complex measures?

I write the details below.

Let $(S, \mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, and $\nu, \mu$ complex measures on $\mathscr{A}$.
We define a complex measure $\tau$ by $\tau := \nu + \mu$.

#### Question 1.

Let $f: S \to \mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function. We consider the following two conditions:
**(1)** $f \in L^1(|\tau|)$
**(2)** $f \in L^1(|\nu|) \cap L^1(|\mu|)$.
I checked that if (2) holds then so does (1). But I don't know whether (2) holds under (1).
Can (2) be proven under (1)?

#### Question 2.

Let $f \in L^1(|\nu|) \cap L^1(|\mu|)$. Then does the following equation hold?:
\begin{equation}
\int_S f d\tau = \int_S f d\nu + \int_S f d\mu.
\end{equation}

(I understand the equation above holds if $\nu$ and $\mu$ are ordinary measures(i.e. $[0, \infty]$-valued measures).)

Thank you in advance.

---

#### Definitions:

We define an integral w.r.t. a complex measure($\mathbb{C}$-valued measure) as follows.

(**Remark**: Complex measures take $\mathbb{C}$-values, so they are not allowed to take infinite values.)

Let $(S, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a complex measure space. For $A \in \mathscr{A}$, we define 
$$
\begin{equation}
    |\mu|(A) := \sup\left\{ \sum_{B \in \mathscr{B}} |\mu(B)|\  \Bigl|\  \mathscr{B} \textrm{ is a finite partition of } A \textrm{ into } \mathscr{A}\textrm{-measurable sets} \right\}.
\end{equation}
$$
It is well-known that $|\mu|$ is a real finite measure. And we can write $\mu_1 (:= \mathrm{Re}\mu) = \mu_1^+ - \mu_1^-$ and $\mu_2 (:= \mathrm{Im}\mu) = \mu_2^+ - \mu_2^-$ by Jordan decomposition, where $\mu_1^\pm$ and $\mu_2^\pm$ are positive finite measures on $\mathscr{A}$.

For $f \in L^1(|\mu|)$, we define the integral of $f$ w.r.t. the complex measure $\mu$ by
\begin{align}
    \int_S f d\mu &:= \int_S f d\mu_1 + i \int_S f d\mu_2,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
    \int_S f d\mu_1 &:= \int_S f d\mu_1^+ - \int_S f d\mu_1^-, \\
    \int_S f d\mu_2 &:= \int_S f d\mu_2^+ - \int_S f d\mu_2^-.
\end{align}

($\int_S f d\mu_1^\pm$ and $\int_S f d\mu_2^\pm$ are the integrals w.r.t. $[0, \infty)$-valued measures, which we are familiar with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1.

Let $\mu = -\nu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0, 1).$ Then $\tau := \mu+\nu$ is the zero measure so every measurable function $f$ is in $L^1(|\tau|)$. But for example $f(x) = 1/x$ is neither in $L^1(|\mu|)$ nor $L^1(|\nu|)$.

#### Question 2.

I give a sketch of a possible proof.

For a complex measure $\tau$ we have by definition
$\int f \, d\tau = \int f \, d(\operatorname{Re}\tau) + i \int f \, d(\operatorname{Im}\tau)$
where $\operatorname{Re}\tau$ and $\operatorname{Im}\tau$ are realvalued measures.

Thus assume that $\tau = \mu + \nu$ are realvalued measures. Integration against such is defined by doing a Jordan decomposition into two ordinary (i.e. nonnegative) measures $\tau^+$ and $\tau^-$ living on disjoint sets, and then setting $\int f \, d\tau = \int f \, d\tau^+ - \int f \, d\tau^-.$

Idea: Let $S_\tau^+ \cup S_\tau^-$, $S_\mu^+ \cup S_\mu^-$, $S_\nu^+ \cup S_\nu^-$ be Hahn decompositions of $S$ for $\tau$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively. Then split $S$ into the eight sets of the form $S_\tau^\pm \cap S_\mu^\pm \cap S_\nu^\pm$ and do integration on each of these. For example, on $S_\tau^+ \cap S_\mu^+ \cap S_\nu^-$ we have 
$$
\int f \, d\tau = \int f \, d\tau^+ = \int f \, d\mu^+ - \int f \, d\nu^- = \int f \, d\mu + \int f \, d\nu.
$$

Then we just add the integrals over all such sets and get the result $\int f \, d\tau = \int f \, d\mu + \int f \, d\nu$ for realvalued measures.

Comment: A measure is non negative. So $\mu =-\nu$ implies $\mu=\nu =0$ which is not a counterexample.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net. We are talking about complex measures here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, if signed measures can take infinite values, your example is a counterexample. But the definition I work with for complex measures, which include signed measures, doesn't allow them to take infinite values.

Comment: @mochimochinoki. You're right. I forgot that a complex measure should be finite. I've modified my example.

Comment: @md2perpe A perfect counterexample! Your answer solved Question 1. Thank you.

Comment: @mochimochinoki. I've now added an answer to Question 2.

Comment: @md2perpe. Thank you very much! My questions are perfectly solved by your answer. Thanks to you, I also found Hahn decomposition is very useful.